# Finding the probability to get red balls in a basket of red and blue balls given that blue balls are returned when picked

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a box of `35 blue balls` and `15 red balls`, we draw a ball one by one and return the picked ball when it is not red.

What is the probability that it will take `exactly 5 draws` to pick a red ball?

What is the expected number of draws that it will take to finally get a red ball?

We had this seatwork and I'm not sure how to go around the problem now that it is essentially "returning" an item. Does the probability remain the same?

Lastly, what probability distribution can I use to model this problem?

Comment: "What is the probability that ... to finish" Finish what?

Comment: It will take `exactly 5 draws` to pick a red ball.

Comment: [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) must be applied for picking a red ball for the first time. Because blue balls are returned the situation does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question: This follows a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) since this is a process involving [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial)  where picking a red ball is defined as success and picking any other ball is defined as failure, there is no replacement, and we need to find the probability that the first success is on the $k^{th}$ trial

Applying the geometric distribution formula we get the result as:

$(\frac{35}{50})^4 \cdot \frac{15}{50}$

Since we have $35+15=50$ balls in total, $35$ are blue and $15$ are red

The expected value of a geometric distribution is $\frac{1}{p}$ where $p$ is the probability of success which is $ \frac{15}{50}$ in our case so the expected value is $ \frac{50}{15}=\frac{10}{3}$  .

Answer (score 0):

Since the blue balls are returned, and you are looking for the first red ball to be extracted, then the situation is like if all the balls were returned, i.e. a sequence of Bernoulli trials.